# Not able to find EJS Language Support Extension in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio, ejs, visual-studio-2022

Not able to find EJS Language Support Extension in Visual Studio 2022. I searched online from extensions as shown below as well as tried installing from website https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DigitalBrainstem.javascript-ejs-support

Not able to do both

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched to Visual Studio Code where I found these features and moved from Visual Studio to Visual Studio Code